# create submit form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i want to make a submit action, so when i click submit the page will not refresh and data i input in `div1` will send to kanjiconverter.php and display it to `div2` by `<?php echo $newkanji ?>`. i have 3 form in these page.

here my kanjiconverter.php. i save a submit code here.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
        $kanji = ($_POST['convertkanji']);

        $replacements = [
        'class="rt">' => "",
        ];
        $newkanji = strtr($kanji, $replacements);
  }
?>
```

and my form code is here. submit button was in `div1` but im using `input` tag not `button` tag.

```
<form id="convertkanji" method="post" action="kanjiconverter.php"></form>
        <form>
          <div class="form-row">

            <!-- START DIV1 HERE -->
          <div id="div1" class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="convertkanji">Kanji Convert</label>
            <textarea id="convertkanji1" name="convertkanji" rows="10" form="convertkanji"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit1" class="btn btn-default" form="convertkanji" value="Convert" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 6px;" />
          </div>
          <!-- Ended DIV1 HERE -->

          <!-- START DIV2 HERE -->
            <div id="div2" class="form-group col-md-6" style="display: none;">
      <label for="kanji">New Kanji</label>
      <textarea id="kanji" name="kanji" rows="12" form="tambahposting"><?php echo $newkanji ?></textarea>
    </div>
          <!-- Ended DIV2 HERE -->
    </form>
```

and heres my jquery script. im place it above `<html>` tag.

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
  $('#div1').show();
  $('#div2').hide();

  $('input[name="submit1"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').show();

    $.post('kanjiconverter.php', $('form').serialize(), function(response) {
      //Your response from the server-side
    })
  });
});
      </script>
```

i make `div2` hide for first and `div1` show. but when i click submit `div1` will hide and `div2` will show.

and i place `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` between `<head>` and `</head>` tag.

the problem is, when i click submit the data i input not showing. only hide and show who was working. i think the data is not send.

Answer (score 0):

You have two opening form tags. Bad HTML. Please review.

Answer (score 0):

The button it's not submiting the form because of the  e.preventDefault(); because if this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered, so the button will not do what it suppose to do that is to submit the form with the data inside. So to fix it you most add this after show and hide: 
    $( "#convertkanji" ).submit();

Comment: not working. that code make me redirect to .../kanjiconverter.php and just showing white page

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `<?php echo $newkanji ?>` on your `div2` because it's on a different file. You should set the `newkanji` from your ajax response, and fix your html markup first, it's missing closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in many things. 
Your `kanjiconverter.php` should like

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
        $kanji = ($_POST['convertkanji']);

        $replacements = [
        'class="rt">' => "",
        ];
        echo $newkanji = strtr($kanji, $replacements);
  }
?>
```

Your `HTML` code should look like :

```
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
    <!-- START DIV1 HERE -->
        <div id="div1" class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="convertkanji">Kanji Convert</label>
            <textarea id="convertkanji1" name="convertkanji" rows="10" form="convertkanji"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit1" class="btn btn-default" form="convertkanji" value="Convert" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 6px;" />
        </div>
    <!-- Ended DIV1 HERE -->

    <!-- START DIV2 HERE -->
    <div id="div2" class="form-group col-md-6" style="display: none;">
        <label for="kanji">New Kanji</label>
        <textarea id="kanji" name="kanji" rows="12" form="tambahposting"></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- Ended DIV2 HERE -->
</form>
```

Your `jQuery` like this :

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#div1').show();
  $('#div2').hide();

  $('input[name="submit1"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').show();

    $.post('kanjiconverter.php', $('form').serialize(), function(response) {
      $('#kanji').html(response);
    })
  });
});
</script>
```

Hope this will work for you.